# extract column names from matrix

Tags: r, max

I want to extract the column name of maximum value in a `matrix.My` code are as following:

```
p <- array(0, c(2, 2, 2))
colnames(p) <- c("within", "out")
rownames(p) <- c("within", "out")
p[, , 1] <- matrix(c(.2, 0.8, .7, .3), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)
p[, , 2] <- matrix(c(.6, 0.4, .9, .1), 2, 2, byrow=TRUE)
p1 <- p[1, , 1]
inds <- which(p1 == max(p1), arr.ind=TRUE)
cnames <- colnames(p1)[inds[1]]
```

When I call cnames it return NULL instead of "out"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your case, `p1` is a vector, so you could use `names` instead of `colnames`. This should work:

```
cnames = names(p1)[inds[1]]
```

Comment: Thank you it works , can you please tell me how I can check that p1 is a vector

Comment: @user `is.vector(p1)`

Answer (score 3):

Instead of separately generating `inds` using `which` and `max` and then using `inds` to index into the names of `p1`, I would generally grab the name of the element returned by `which.max` to find the name of the maximum element in a named vector:

```
names(which.max(p1))
# [1] "out"
```